# ASP.NET MVC 5 - redirect from view only once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hy,

I'm trying to redirect users which has deactivated javascript with following code in the main layout (_Layout.cshtml):

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/Error/NoJavascript" />
</noscript>
```

Rather it works, but it refreshes every time. How can I redirect only once instead of every time?

I've found this code sample, but it doesn't let me compile (error message: can't implicite convert from void to object) I use this code sample in my view (_Layout.cshtml):

```
@Response.Redirect("/Error/NoJavascript")
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple static HTML file for this special case which `has not` this meta data:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=@Url.Content("~/Content/NoScript.html")" />
```

Your returned view from the `Error/NoJavascript` action method has a reference to the layout page automatically or just set its layout to null.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help .. the layout solution is great for me.